# Building bullet3 on Windows 10 - not all libraries installed

Tags: cmake, bulletphysics, bullet

I have built bullet3-3.08 on Windows using cmake (commands have been executed from the build folder created in the bullet3-3.08 directory):

```
cmake -G "Visual Studio 16 2019" -A x64 -D "CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=C:/Workspace/MyLibs/bullet3-3.08" ..
cmake --build . --config Release --parallel 8 --target install
```

I have noticed that the installation folder doesn't contain all built libraries, for example `BulletCollision.lib` is present the `build/lib/Release` folder but hasn't been installed in the `C:/Workspace/MyLibs/bullet3-3.08/lib` Moreover `C:/Workspace/MyLibs/bullet3-3.08/include` directory doesn't contain all headers, for example `btBulletDynamicsCommon.h`

How to fix that ? I don't want to copy headers/libs manually.

Comment: Did you already tried to add the option `-DINSTALL_LIBS=ON` to your CMake command line? For Visual Studio project files the libs are not  installed by default.

Comment: It works, thanks. I haven't noticed that option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When building bullet3-3.08 on Windows with Visual Studio project files the libraries are not installed by default.

You need to add `-DINSTALL_LIBS=ON` to your command line to enable the installation, e.g.

```
cmake -G "Visual Studio 16 2019" -A x64 -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=C:/Workspace/MyLibs/bullet3-3.08 -DINSTALL_LIBS=ON ..
```